# "jp@gc - Response Times Over Time" Listener in JMeter is not showing max response time which is shown in summary report listeners it shows the average

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want the response time graph to show the maximum response time taken but the graph is not showing the correct response times. As it is showing max Avg time as 8395 ms while I want it to show details of max response time details where max time was 23510 ms.

Response time graph listener actually shows the details of each sampler the average response time in milliseconds. But can I change it to show max response time? Please guide.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found solution to get the response time graph on basis of Max response time.

There is a graph in JMeter HTML report which gets generated by default when you generate the HTML report. Response time percentiles over time and there i disabled all others except max response time.

[image]